# Magento 2: Import CSV File Size

Tags: magento2, product, php, import

When we import Product CSV from Admin it says

> Make sure your file isn't more than 2M.

How to increase this size?  I have 5M file size. Don't want to create multiple CSV files with each 2M

Comment: You have to change upload_max_filesize value in php.ini.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

find your **php.ini** file, for mine it is in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

change the value of below line as per your interest

> upload_max_filesize = 3M

after that restart your **mysql** and **apache** server, load the page again the changes get affect

[image]

also increase the execution time, it is help to avoid time out issue.

Comment: Oh. I though Magento Related Issue. But it didn't. Works fine. Here you go :)

Comment: I just updated the php.ini with 512M. But I could only import 8M data. Is that the maximum?

Comment: @TSGuhan you may have already discover the issue but I believe the reason you are stuck at 8M is due to the `post_max_size` in the php.ini. Increasing this to 512M will most likely allow you to upload bigger files.

Answer (score 8):

Magento 2 import process loads the CSV data into Mysql database in the table `importexport_importdata`.

You need to make sure that the Mysql parameter `'max_allowed_packet'` is greater than `7.5M` which correspond to `5M * 1.5` in your context.

And check also your PHP setting :

```
'post_max_size' 

'upload_max_filesize'
```

In your context, updating the PHP setting `upload_max_filesize` is enough, but if the file size increase, update the Mysql parameter.

Comment: post_max_size did the trick for me. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to increase the file size via cpanel's mulit php editor with my hosting company.