# Upload CSV file size limit

Tags: php, server-setup, upload, magento2.4

I have 13mb file I want to upload, I've increased the `php.ini` file to 100MB but Magento upload page still giving me the warning to make sure the file is less than 8MB.

is it possible to upload the CSV product file more than 8MB?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you changed in a wrong file or you didn't restart your services to load the change.

Run this command below to check the upload limits.

```
php -i | grep upload
```

[image: Magento 2.4 upload limits]

Answer (score 0):

```
post_max_size = 32M
```

Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Answer (score 0):

**As you said you already change the value php.ini file and i am considering you restart apache or nginx**
then you can consider those point (i am not sure)

1. check if you have any file called **.user.ini** in magento install root directory then increase value from there
2. does .htaccess set like **php_value post_max_size 8M**. ?
3. something in you file coded to set php.ini value please do check this type of code: **ini_set('post_max_size','8M');**

Answer (score 0):

Find your php.ini file, for mine it is in **`/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`**.

change the value of below line as per your interest

> **`upload_max_filesize = 3M`**

After that restart your mysql and apache server, load the page again the changes get affect

**[image: NOTE :-]**

Also increase the execution time, it is help to avoid time out issue.

And get more information check this link :-

**[Magento 2: Import CSV File Size](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/magento-2-import-csv-file-size)**

And Second PHP official Link :-

**https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size**

**`THANKS.`**